# Which is efficient among `Padding` vs `SizedBox`?

Tags: flutter

### Background:

`SizedBox` class can be used to insert empty space between widgets, like `SizedBox(height: 8)`, and also with `Padding` class using `EdgeInsets` class,

### `SizedBox` cannot be used everywhere.

I know this, and also where ever it can be, its use is different than `Padding`,

### But

Im interested in:

Using `ListView.builder` with each child wrapped in `Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4))`,

vs

Using `ListView.separated` with `SizedBox(height: 8)` as separator,

### Reason behind curiosity:

`Padding` has to create two(top and bottom) empty spaces, instead of one, as in the case of `SizedBox`,

### The Real question:

If we ignore the cases where `Padding` can be used, but not `SizedBox`, then which one would be more efficient and recommended way to achieving empty space,

thanking you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you should take in consider is **SizedBox** Allow you applies constraints to it's child.

About empty spaces, they do the same thing literally. At most you'll have a nanosecond worth of difference, especially if both in your code was a **const**,

About the **ListView.builder** or **ListView.separated**, both have a use cases depend on what you want to do, Like **separated Builder** allow you to customize widget for each item, etc.

in case in your question, Use whatever fits you the best.
The gain is so minimal you'll never ever notice a difference. So take what is clearer.

### ***EDIT: (In case someone come in the future)

after some experiences, there is one more thing we should take into consideration, 
padding creates a space that is included with its child, so in cases of buttons, IconButton, in common cases it would be better to use padding since this space will be clickable, and this will improve user experience.

Example: 
**instead of:**

```
const Row(
        children: [
          /// some of widgets
          SizedBox(width: 8,),
          InkWell(
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8,),
        ],
      )
```

**Use:**

```
 const Row(
        children: [
          /// some of widgets
          InkWell(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: Yeah I got your point, and after 3 years of experience, I can say to you: Use whatever fits you the best. 
and If both give you the best, then Use **SizedBox**, it will be reduce the time complexity by Nano seconds.

Comment: this is almost the answer, so i select, but the definite answer is, `SizedBox` is performant, as it does less calculations internally, and only the work needed, is done

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on your use case, but from experience. Sized Box is better and more performant than Padding for just an empty space.

Also depending on the use case, you might find it appropriate to make use of other widgets like Spacer.
Spacer is best for creating an empty space in a Row. This is because you do not need to constrain its size but just optionally provide a flex value. This way, it becomes more useful than both Padding and SizedBox.